# не запускается exe файл pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь отрыть файл скомпилированный через pyinstaller, а файл просто открывается и закрывается

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно дело в том что у вас не предусмотренно ожидание завершения программы. Код доходит логического конца и выводя информацию логично закрывается. Добавьте в конце программы какой нибудь **`input("Нажмите Enter для выхода")`**.

Comment: Добавил, ничего не поменялось..

Comment: вам стоит привести фрагменты кода что бы мы могли лучше разобраться и то как вы собираете

Comment: import numexpr
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back
init()

print(Fore.CYAN)

expr = input("Введите мат. операцию:")
result = numexpr.evaluate(expr)

print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX)
print(f"Ответ: {result}")
input("Нажмите Enter для выхода")